# Connecting to Exchange with Windows Mail vs. Outlook 2013

Tags: windows-mail, microsoft-outlook-2013

Why would I be able to connect to an Exchange server with the Windows 8 Mail app, but not Outlook 2013?

When configuring Windows 8, all I provided was the server, domain, username, password, and I checked the SSL required box too. I can't seem to figure out how to add the account in the same way to Outlook.